# Handling business rule exceptions in business logic layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, class-library, n-tier-architecture

What's the best way to handle business logic violations/exceptions in my ASP.NET MVC app? Do I throw an exception with an Http status code?

In my application, I have multiple projects e.g. MVC, business logic, DAL/Infrastructure, etc.

Let's say, I get a request from a user who is not authorized to see that information. I figure out that the user is not authorized in the business logic layer which is a class library project. What's the right way to tell the MVC front end that the user is not authorized to get that information?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to validate whether the user is authorized or not is at controller or action level. That means, decorate your controller or action with `Authorize` attribute, and specify what users/ roles has access over the same. It shouldn't be at business logic level.

Validation such as required field, data types, range validations, etc should be performed using data annotations, and also, through Javascripts, for client-side validations.

For other business validations (For example, if something fails at database level, or some business logic violdation) , the best approach is to write validation logic in the business layer and throw the exception. Your MVC project should ideally should handle the exception and display a common error page and log the errors in event log or database or file system using packages such as ELMAH or NLOG.